# How to select oldest date row from each product using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I would like to get the oldest only one from every type product and sum of the prices listed in `listofproduct` table. Another thing is to search only between prodacts that has at least one peace on lager.

With the SQL I managed to get all the products has at least one on the stock. But the rest I am stack...

So the sum cold be done later, that was my plan, but if you have better idea feel free to write

Here is my data:

```sql
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| IDProizvoda | NazivProizvoda | DatumKupovine | NaLageru |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
|          77 | Cokolada       | 25-Feb-20     |        2 |
|          44 | fgyhufrthr     | 06-Aug-20     |        5 |
|          55 | Auto           | 06-Aug-23     |        0 |
|          55 | Auto           | 11-Aug-20     |      200 |
|          77 | Cokolada       | 06-Aug-27     |        0 |
|          77 | Cokolada       | 25-Feb-20     |       10 |
|          77 | Cokolada       | 25-Jan-20     |      555 |
|          77 | Cokolada       | 25-Mar-20     |       40 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
```

```cs
    Access.ExeQuery("SELECT * FROM Products " &
                    "WHERE IDProizvoda IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@listofproduct, ',')) " &
                    "AND NaLageru > 0 ")
```

I tried to add `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but it does not worked because i choose the whole table. But I need `Product ID` and `Stock` field for edit it later, to subtract one from the stock for those products.

I would like to get the result:

```sql
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| IDProizvoda | NazivProizvoda | DatumKupovine | NaLageru |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
|          44 | fgyhufrthr     | 06-Aug-20     |        5 |
|          55 | Auto           | 11-Aug-20     |      200 |
|          77 | Cokolada       | 25-Jan-20     |      555 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag, please.

Comment: More infos added

Comment: What if there's a tie and there's more than 1 "oldest"?  How to pick only 1?

Comment: If i save Timestamp, i think it saves seconds too, so theoretically i think there should not be two, but anyway if there is two I am more than fine with one of them in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a Cross Apply, this would be your SQL query:

```
Select  P.IDProizvoda,
        P.NazivProizvoda,
        N.DatumKupovine,
        N.NaLageru,
        N.IDKupovine,
        N.CenaPoKomadu
        From 
products P
Cross Apply
(
    Select top 1    DatumKupovine,
                    NaLageru,
                    IDKupovine,
                    CenaPoKomadu
    From products P2
    where P2.IDProizvoda = P.IDProizvoda
    and P2.NaLageru > 0 
    order by DatumKupovine
)  N
group by P.IDProizvoda, P.NazivProizvoda, N.DatumKupovine, N.NaLageru, N.IDKupovine, N.CenaPoKomadu
```

And this your ExeQuery:

```
Access.ExeQuery("Select P.IDProizvoda, P.NazivProizvoda, N.DatumKupovine, N.NaLageru, N.IDKupovine, N.CenaPoKomadu From products P " &
        " Cross Apply( Select top 1 DatumKupovine, NaLageru, IDKupovine, CenaPoKomadu From products P2 where P2.IDProizvoda = P.IDProizvoda and P2.NaLageru > 0 order by DatumKupovine)  N " &
        " where P.IDProizvoda in (Select value From STRING_SPLIT(@listofproduct, ',')) " &
        " group by P.IDProizvoda,   P.NazivProizvoda, N.DatumKupovine, N.NaLageru, N.IDKupovine, N.CenaPoKomadu " )
```

Comment: Almost good, the problem is the order of choice, when I tested it, it first choose the oldest, but..... if it first choose the oldest the result is wrong, sometimes it choose the one that is 0 on lager....

So In my opinion it should first find all the rows where NaLageru is not 0, than to chose the oldest date. Do you get what I need? 

Anyway good code, just to somehow change this.

Comment: Oh I get what you say, just updated the query to reflect the oldest date for NaLageru > 0.

Comment: Thank you. Las one, I tried, but i think i did something wrong because it was not good...
So I tried to get two more columns , because i will need that later, IDKupovine, and CenaPoKomadu, how I can add them? Is it possible?

Comment: If those columns are form the same table, you need to add them inside the Cross Apply and include them in the Select and Group By. I updated the query to include them, I'm assuming both columns are from the original table.

Comment: Works. Thank you a lot! :) I will dig deeper in this Cross Apply thing!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just aggregation with a filter:

```
SELECT IDProizvoda, NazivProizvoda, MAX(DatumKupovine),
       SUM(NaLegaru)
FROM Products p
WHERE NaLegaru > 0
GROUP BY IDProizvoda, NazivProizvoda;
```

Comment: This does not work for me, missing some stuff, but thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (
       partition by NazivProizvoda
       order by DatumKupovine
    ) as rn
    FROM Products
    WHERE IDProizvoda IN (
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@listofproduct, ',')
    )
        AND NaLageru > 0
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

By way of explanation, I'm using a common table expression to select the superset of the data you want by criteria and adding a column that enumerates each row within a group (a group being defined here as having `NazivProizvoda` be the same) in order of the `DatumKupovine`). With that done, anything that admits the value of 1 for that enumeration will be the oldest in the group. If you data is such that more than one row can be the oldest, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I tried "iceblade"s solution, and it worked, I did not tried yours, yet, but thank you for all the effort and explaining. Explaining helped a lot.